# Fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observe doesn't call with kodein

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, kodein

i'm making an app and i want to separate my UI logic into multiple UI classes with BaseUi class being lifecycle aware. I'm using Kodein as my DI and i have an issue with `fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observe` not being called when instance of my ui class is being retrieved by Kodein.
Here is my Fragment class:

```
class ListFragment : Fragment(), DIAware {

    override val di: DI by closestDI()
    override val diTrigger: DITrigger = DITrigger()

    private var binding: FragmentMoviesBinding? = null

    private val fragmentBinding get() = binding

    private val kodeinMoviesUi: MoviesUi by instance() //fragment does not observe viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData

    private val moviesUi: MoviesUi = MoviesUi(this) //fragment now observe viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentMoviesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        diTrigger.trigger()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
    }
}
```

BaseUi class:

```
abstract class BaseUi<F : Fragment>(private val fragment: F) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observe(fragment, { subscribeToLifecycle() })
    }

    private fun subscribeToLifecycle() {
        fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
            fun onCreate() {
                onViewCreated()
            }
        })
    }

    abstract fun onViewCreated()
}
```

And UiModule:

```
val uiModule = DI.Module("uiModule") {
    bind<ListFragment>() with provider { ListFragment() }
    bind<MoviesUi>() with provider { MoviesUi(instance()) }
}
```

Comment: Fragments should not be created by the DI framework, unless you are also using a custom FragmentFactory.

Comment: Also check this article because you inherited a bug in your lifecycle observing logic: https://itnext.io/an-update-to-the-fragmentviewbindingdelegate-the-bug-weve-inherited-from-autoclearedvalue-7fc0a89fcae1

Answer (score 0):

*Cross post from https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/353*

Here is your problem `bind<ListFragment>() with provider { ListFragment() }`.

You bound the `ListFragment` with a provider, meaning every time you ask to the container it will create an instance of `ListFragment`. So, when you inject `MoviesUi` with `private val kodeinMoviesUi: MoviesUi by instance()`, it gets another instance of `ListFragment`.

I suggest that you define the binding for `MoviesUi` as a factory, waiting to receive a `ListFragment` instance:
`bind<MoviesUi>() with factory {fragment: ListFragment -> MoviesUi(fragment) }`
then you can inject it in the `ListFragment` like:
`private val kodeinMoviesUi: MoviesUi by instance(args = this)`